# Is there a way to import a ruleset from a css module in react?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, css-loader, css-modules

Currently I'm doing a very standard

```
import styles from './register.module.less'
<div className={styles.requestedOverlay} ></div>
```

in my react app. I've ended up with a use case for passing in rules as raw css instead of using the `styles.className` syntax. Something like:

```
import rawStyles from './register.module.less'
<Component css={styles.selectorAsRawCssRules} />
```

Is there a way to do that? Is there currently a webpack loader for it?

Comment: As far as I know, it’s not possible at the moment using Webpack alone. You’d need to load and parse CSS separately from building style sources and modules to extract style properties from the CSS.

Comment: If nobody has a way to do it I'm thinking about writing a loader ‍♀️

Comment: I also didn't find a loader that would give you expected results, but if you plan to write one yourself, you could use https://github.com/reworkcss/css as a base. You should also consider if you want to support pseudoselectors because they may be tricky.

Comment: Yeah, that's something that I'm between excited to solve, and dreading :)